# Could not build the application for the simulator from Android Studio

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

Why am I unable to launch my app from android studio where I can successfully run the app from xcode? I am facing this issue after integrating OneSignal to my project.

```
Launching lib/main_development.dart on iPhone 8 Plus in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           24.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    ld: in /Users/.../customer_app_flutter/ios/Pods/OneSignal/iOS_SDK/OneSignalSDK/Framework/OneSignal.framework/OneSignal(OneSignal-arm64-master.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/.../customer_app_flutter/ios/Pods/OneSignal/iOS_SDK/OneSignalSDK/Framework/OneSignal.framework/OneSignal'
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
    /Users/.../customer_app_flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Mantle' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/.../customer_app_flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'libwebp' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/.../customer_app_flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/.../customer_app_flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/.../customer_app_flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'OrderedSet' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/.../customer_app_flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/.../customer_app_flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'FBSDKCoreKit' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/.../customer_app_flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'OneSignalXCFramework' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/.../customer_app_flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'OneSignal' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/.../customer_app_flutter/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 8 Plus.
```

Comment: have you updated minimum deployment target?

Comment: Yes i updated deployment targets  as well as minimumOSVersion in AppFrameworkInfo.plist

Answer (score 2):

open the iOS project in Xcode and change `Validate Workspace` setting in Build `Settings` to `YES`

Answer (score 0):

While adding OneSignal Notification Service Extension one must select Cancel. And this is why i was facing these issues as I had selected Activate option. Follow this [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk-setup) to integrate OneSignal successfully

[image]